# Smartdiagram clipping a background picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, overpic, smartdiagram

I am trying to use [smartdiagram](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/smartdiagram) but with a background image clipped to the shape of the node for the "title" node. Then write over this some text. The MWE below shows an example of as far as I got but without the clipping. Is this possible?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\begin{document}
\smartdiagram[descriptive diagram]
{{
{
\begin{overpic}[width=\textwidth]{sil}
\put(1,30){Overlay}
\end{overpic}},{Description}},
{Another one, description},
}
\end{document}
```

[image: Final result]

Comment: Could try to better explain what you want the result to look like?  I don't quite understand the problem.

Comment: Sorry about that. I want the background image "TeX" to cover the whole red circle, clipped into that circular shape.

While at it, I would like to be able to reduce the opacity of the background image too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, Claudio, another hack. One can "hack" single nodes by introducing a counter and tell Ti*k*Z what to do with that node. It is advantageous to do these hacks within a TeX group (but of course for a document consisting only of that diagram this does not really matter). The "hack" steps a counter and will modify a certain node (node # 1 in this case) with a `\tikzset` command. In this case, one can use a path picture because this will be clipped at the node boundaries.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\newcounter{pft}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\newcommand\hack{\tikzset{nodes={/utils/exec={\stepcounter{pft}
\ifnum\value{pft}=1\relax
\tikzset{path picture={\node at (path picture bounding box.center)
{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};}}
\fi}}}}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={execute at begin picture=\hack}}
\setcounter{pft}{0}%
\smartdiagram[descriptive diagram]
{{
{Overlay},{Description}},
{Another one, description},
}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want? I will edit/update if required.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\begin{document}
\smartdiagram[descriptive diagram]
{
  {
    {\begin{overpic}[width=\textwidth]{sil}
      \put(1,30){}
     \end{overpic}},{Description}
  },
  {Another one, description},
}
\end{document}
```

Using the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlym0.png) (I just downloaded from TeX.SE and cropped it), I get:

[image]

Comment: I believe only difference from the one I have shown is that this new image has a transparent background. What I want is something like this. The image is cropped to the circle and text is overlaid.

http://oi60.tinypic.com/fdyqzr.jpg

Comment: @ulugeyik I'm confused about the "overlay" text in your MWE. Is this meant to be in the final output or just to illustrate what you want overlaid?

Comment: The idea is to use a picture, for example, of an instrument as the background of the circle, then overlay a descriptive text over it. I do not want to include the text as part of the graphic since the text may change for every presentation.